# What is actually going on when we say $S^1 = [0, 1]/{\sim}$?

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

I have just started reading a Dynamical Systems book, which makes use of some Topology concepts. I know some Analysis (I have gone through most of baby Rudin), but I've never taken a Topology class before; thus I am having trouble with some of the concepts. For example, consider the following passage:

> Consider the unit circle $S^1 = [0, 1]/{\sim}$, where $\sim$ indicates that $0$ and $1$ are identified. Addition mod 1 makes $S^1$ an abelian group. The natural distance on $[0, 1]$ induces a distance on $S^1$; specifically,
> $$d(x, y) = \min(|x-y|, 1-|x-y|).$$
> Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$ gives a natural measure on $S^1$, also called Lebesgue measure.

Because I've heard people talk about Topology before, I do have a rough idea of what $S^1 = [0, 1]/{\sim}$ means. I think that $S^1$ is, formally, $\{(x, y \in \mathbb{R}^2|x^2 + y^2 = 1)\}$. We thing of stretching the interval $[0, 1]$ to a length of $2 \pi$ (but still keeping the same markings on the segment, so that the ends are still labeled $0$ and $1$), and then wrapping it around the unit circle.

However, I'm not sure what's going on formally here. I assume that $[0, 1]/{\sim}$ is (at least) a set. What are its elements?

Thank you.

Comment: One day (hopefully soon) you will learn the notion of "equivalence relation" and "equivalence classes".  Then you will have a *formal* way to think of $[0,1]/\sim$.  Until then, think of it as just a convenient informal description.

Comment: @GEdgar I am familiar with these notions. What equivalence relation does ~ stand for in this example?

Comment: In this example $\sim$ stands for "$0$ and $1$ are identified".  So $x \sim y$ means either $x=y$ or $x,y = 0,1$ in some order.

Comment: @GEdgar Oh okay. So would it be formally correct to say that $[0, 1]/$~ $= \{\{x\}| x \in (0, 1) \} \cup \{0, 1\}$?

Comment: I mean I know that when people write $[0, 1]/$~ they mean it as a topological space, but I just mean as a set.

Comment: I think what you mean is correct, but I will be pedantic and point out that I think you mean $\{ \{x\} | x \in (0,1)\} \cup \{\{0,1\}\}$. In any case, the point is that you can write a homeomorphism (that is, an isomorphism of topological spaces) between $[0,1]/\sim$ and $S^1$.

Comment: @BrianShin Ah yes indeed, it shoul've been $\{ \{0, 1 \} \}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally, when we write $[0,1]/\sim = S^1$, we mean we have a particular isomorphisms (of sets, topological spaces, and groups) between these two things in mind. The one I have in mind is $f : [0,1]/\sim \to S^1$ given by $f([t]) = (\cos(2\pi t), \sin(2\pi t))$. Here, I write $[t]$ for the equivalence class of $t$.